# Where do I place generated javadoc html files?

Tags: java, javadoc

Thanks to a lot of research and some answers found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468669/how-to-generate-javadoc). I have been able to use the javadoc command to generate some html files. My question is, once I have successfully generated these files, where do I place them (directory) so that they show up as javadoc when using my compiled jar library?

Comment: in the library folder!

Comment: Can you explain a little more about that. Where like in the root of the library project?

Comment: First of all,specify your IDE. If it is NetBeans,I can  totally help you,else,I'll try my best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most IDEs allow you to select a JAR and then set the folder or JAR which contains the javadoc in a properties dialog.

That said, javadoc is only useful when it was created with a lot of care. Most of the time, the sources are much more useful (especially since sources can't lie, they contain all the corner cases, people are used to read source code and most developers are very, very bad at writing documentation).

All IDEs I know (Eclipse, IDEA, Netbeans) can extract javadoc from a JAR which contains the sources at runtime.

Comment: Ok so I would have to distribute the folder with the jar, and devs would have to select it from within their IDE. There is no way to include it with the JAR to begin with?

Comment: There is no way to include it in the JAR but you can package all the files in a JAR, so developers just have to deal with two JAR files.

Comment: Ok so make my lib.jar and a lib-javadoc.jar?

Comment: @Kyle: I can't answer that in a comment. Ask a new question for that.

Answer (score 0):

By default, after command execution in the Command Prompt:

```
javadoc -d doc C:\YourProjects\ProjectName\src\*
```

Javadoc could save generated files to:

> C:\Users\USERNAME\doc