# how to create function description / definition in java

Tags: java

Is there someone here can give me idea or informations on how to create a functions definition, same to what we got when we write the signature of a function and than we press `ctrl + space`, in other world, like this :

```
File file = new File    ( and when we pressed ctrl+space we got as showing in the picture bellow)
```

[image: After pressing ctrl + space]

I googled a lot but i didn't found any solutions, thanks if someone here can help me.

Comment: its called JavaDoc...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468669/how-to-generate-javadoc?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Thank you Eran, it helped me, i used a wrong keywords when i googled ... thank you dear :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read about the [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html).

Look the `File` class source for an example:

```
/**
 * Creates a new <code>File</code> instance by converting the given
 * pathname string into an abstract pathname.  If the given string is
 * the empty string, then the result is the empty abstract pathname.
 *
 * @param   pathname  A pathname string
 * @throws  NullPointerException
 *          If the <code>pathname</code> argument is <code>null</code>
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a good manual about [javadocs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)