# Best way to access documentation inside my code

Tags: java, file, csv, text

I'm trying to add a functionality where users can lookup documentation for commands - its a command line based program with various commands they can enter.

I think the simplest thing to do is store the docs in an external file but I'm not sure what my best option would be. Text files just seem a bit sloppy, csv is more what I had in mind but dealing with commas in the docs is also not ideal. A dictionary(like json) would be great but I'm not sure how I could read it with Java. I can't use 3rd part libraries.

Comment: Do you want a simple `Readme` file the user would load into their favorite text editor and read or some mechanism (like a man page) that your program would provide?

Comment: The program is all in the command line. Its basically the 'man' function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to write javadocs comments and then export it (if you want).
User can also access the documentation for commands when using your libraries.

[Tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html)

Example:

```
/**
 * Returns an Image object that can then be painted on the screen. 
 * The url argument must specify an absolute {@link URL}. The name
 * argument is a specifier that is relative to the url argument. 
 * <p>
 * This method always returns immediately, whether or not the 
 * image exists. When this applet attempts to draw the image on
 * the screen, the data will be loaded. The graphics primitives 
 * that draw the image will incrementally paint on the screen. 
 *
 * @param  url  an absolute URL giving the base location of the image
 * @param  name the location of the image, relative to the url argument
 * @return      the image at the specified URL
 * @see         Image
 */
 public Image getImage(URL url, String name) {
        try {
            return getImage(new URL(url, name));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            return null;
        }
 }
```

[Export javadocs to html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468669/how-to-generate-javadoc-html-in-eclipse?answertab=oldest#tab-top)