# JavaDocs option not visible in my Eclipse Project menu

Tags: java, groovy, javadoc, groovydoc

I was trying to follow this posting
[How to generate Javadoc HTML in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468669/how-to-generate-javadoc-html-in-eclipse)
But in my Eclipse Neon 3 or Mars 2, versions I can't see the menu options like
Project --> Generate JavaDocs...
Do I need to install any plugins or do some preparation step ?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too.

I searched a bit in the internet and found a solution back in the day.

I am still not sure why it worked though.

- Click on `Window` `->` `Perspective` `->` `Customize Perspective`
- Check the "`Java Navigation Group`".

Comment: I  reached the similar solution. Meaning changing into the Java Perspective. I was originally in a workfusion studio perspective, which uses groovy and web harvest tags. It makes sense.